# If statement not executed slows program

Tags: if-statement, arduino

I have an `if` statement that is currently never executed, however if I print something to the screen it takes over ten times longer for the program to run than if a variable is declared. Doing a bit of research online this seems to be some kind of branch prediction issue. Is there anything I can do to improve the program speed?

Basically both myTest and myTest_new return the same thing except one is a macro and one is a function. I am just monitoring the time it takes for bitTest to execute. and it executes in 3 seconds with just declaration in if statement but takes over a minute when Serial.print is in if statement even though neither are executed.

```
void bitTest()
{
  int count = 0;
  Serial1.println("New Test");
  int lastint = 0;
  Serial1.println("int");
  for (int index = -2147483647; index <= 2147483647; index+=1000) {
    if (index <= 0 && lastint > 0) {
      break;
    }
    lastint = index;   

    for (int num = 0; num <= 31; num++) {
      ++1000;
      int vcr1 = myTest(index, num);
      int vcr2 = myTest_new(index, num);
      if (vcr1 != vcr2) {
        Serial1.println("Test"); // leave this println() and it takes 300 seconds for the test to run
        //int x = 0;
      }
    } // if (index)
  } // for (index)



  Serial1.print("count = ");

  Serial1.println(count);

  return;

}
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  First off priting to the terminal is very slow compared to "not printing", as you have learned.  But I fail to what priting has to do with declring your variable.  As it stands this this question may be closed because it is not clear

Comment: @jimmcnamara pretty sure what OP wants to say is "*`if` clause's content is never executed, so why does it make a difference to performance what's inside that clause?*"

Comment: by slow I mean taking over a minute to execute the program. This is an extreme case of slow

Comment: what?! ok, these lines will *never* take a minute to execute, no matter what you do. You have a bug somewhere else

Comment: In this case, your code is extremely incomplete. Or you're mistaken, and the the `if` clause is executed, and something in `Serial.print` takes so long.

Comment: By the way, this is NOT C, pretty sure. OP, what language is this *really*?

Comment: So, does `Serial` happen to be a serial device with a timeout of, say, 15 seconds? Such that outputting, say, 4 characters, will take one minute if for whatever reason the device isn't ready/connected? Something the like?

Comment: Im going to edit the question to include more of the code. Its arduino not C,

Comment: It would have helped enormously to have said "arduino" in the question.

Comment: `index <= 2147483647` is always true with a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: So the content of the `if` clause **is** sometimes executed, right?

Comment: no the if statement is never executed. This is what Im saying. vcr1 and vcr2 return the same value so they always equal eachother.

Comment: Well, you have a bug in your for loop.

Comment: After all, this question is impossible to answer; you will need to correct your program and come back with the corrected version. Voting to close this as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

It is much less likely to be caused by a branch prediction (that branch prediction shouldn't be influenced by what you do inside your code) but by the fact that

```
{
   int x = 0;
}
```

simply does nothing, because the scope of `x` ends at `}`, so that the compiler simply ditches the whole `if` clause, including the check. Note that this is only possible because the expression that `if` checks has no side effects, and neither does the block that would get executed.

By the way, the code you showed would usually directly be "compiled away", because the compiler, at compile time, can determine whether the `if` clause could ever be executed, unless you explicitly tell the compiler to omit such safe optimizations. Hence, I kind of doubt your "10 times as slow" measurement. Either the code you're showing isn't the actual example on which you demonstrate this, or you should turn on compiler optimization prior to doing performance comparisons.

Comment: Also, I/O is notoriously slow, especially to console.

Comment: @EOF: doesn't matter, as OP claims it's never executed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your program takes forever is that it's buggy:

```
for (int index = -2147483647; index <= 2147483647; index+=1000) {
```

simply: at a very large `index` close to the maximum integer value, a wrap-around will occur. There's no "correct" way for your program to terminate. Hence you invented your strange `lastint > 0` checking.

Now, fix up the loop (I mean, you're really just using every 1000th element, so why not simply loop index from 0 to 2*2147483?)

```
  ++1000;
```

should be illegal in C, because you can't increase a constant numeral. This is very much WTF.

All in all, your program is a mess. Re-write it, and debug a clean, well-defined version of it.